# Get UserName and Date when i click on a button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-foundation

My HTML code is :

`<button id="app1" type="button"onclick="javascript:Approver(ProspectID);">Approver</button>`

My JS code :

```
function Approver(ProspectID) {


var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
});

function onSuccess(data, request) {

    var loginName = data.d.Title;

    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(ListNameProspect);
    var Linked = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Approverun": loginName,
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + ListNameProspect + "')/items(" + ProspectID + ")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(Linked),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function () {
            RetrieveProspect(ProspectID);

        },
        error: function (Rep, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Update failed." + Rep.responseText + " " + errorThrown.toString())
        }
    });

}

function onError(error) {
    alert("error");
}
```

}

With this code i just get the Login name.**I want to get the date and time too when clicking Approver**

Comment: Do you want to to get the date and time when user clicks on the approver button or something else??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript code, you can get the date and time very easily with following code:

```
var dateTimeNow = new Date();
```

If you want to store this date & time in list:

1. By default in SharePoint we get "Created" column which stores the date time whenever we add new item in list.
2. And if you want to store this time in another field on your own, you need to add one more column in list and one property in your data("Linked") which you are using in POST call.
3. For this you need to pass the date in ISO format. You can convert your date in ISO format using following code:

`var isoFormatedDate = dateTimeNow.toISOString();`